# Loop through roles and give the user a corresponding role to the one it currently has

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I need to make it so the bot searches through the priority list of corresponding roles, finds one that matches the one the user currently has and gives out a corresponding one based on the list. After that, it stops searching and moves on. If the user does not have the first role, it just skips to the next one and keeps comparing untill it finds a match.

This is what I have right now. It seems to loop through the list, but stops when it hits the else, since I wasn't able to make it go back to searching.

```
if(
    newMember.roles.cache.has(yellow) &&
    newMember.roles.cache.has(role2) == false
)   {
    newMember.roles.remove(yellow)

    var server_roles = {role2:yellow, role1:blue};

    for (var prop in server_roles) {
        
        if (
            newMember.roles.cache.has(prop)

        )   {
            console.log("User has role: " + prop)
            newMember.roles.add(server_roles[prop])
            break

        }else(
            console.log("User does not have: " + prop)
            // Continue searching through the list
        )

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use CONTINUE instead of BREAK.

reference from

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp

"The break statement "jumps out" of a loop."

"The continue statement "jumps over" one iteration in the loop."

Comment: The idea to continue on the loop until a match is found and to jump out of it once that happens. So I do, indeed, need it to break after the "if" statement is fullfilled, but I need it to continue on the loop during the "else" statement which I have not been able to do, since it didn't allow me to put a "continue" statement there.